# Spring SessionRegistryImpl not getting correct sessionId

Tags: java, spring, session, jakarta-ee, logging

I'm trying to do an access log. So far I can successfully log the session's beginning, with this class:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter extends J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {

    @Autowired
    AccessLogService accessLogService;

    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {

        if (authentication.isAuthenticated()) {

            String authenticatedUser = authentication.getName();
            WebAuthenticationDetails wad = (WebAuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails();

            accessLogService.addAccessLog("IP: "  + wad.getRemoteAddress(), authenticatedUser, request.getSession().getId());           

        }
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

That's working fine. I have this class for the logout part:

```
public class CustomSecurityContextLogoutHandler extends SecurityContextLogoutHandler {

   @Autowired
   private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

   @Autowired
   private AccessLogDAO accessLogDAO;

   private boolean deleteLtpaCookies = Boolean.FALSE;

    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {

    if (authentication != null && authentication.getPrincipal() != null) {
        List<SessionInformation> sessions = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(((User) authentication.getPrincipal()), false);
        if (sessions != null) {
            for (SessionInformation sessionInformation : sessions) {
                List<String> sessionsToClose = new ArrayList<String>();
                sessionsToClose.add(sessionInformation.getSessionId());
                accessLogDAO.closeAccessLog(sessionsToClose);

                sessionInformation.expireNow();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But when I do

```
List<SessionInformation> sessions = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(((User) authentication.getPrincipal()), false)
```

sessions comes null. When I debugged the **[SessionRegistryImpl](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/session/SessionRegistryImpl.html)** I found that the problem is at *getAllSessions*'s first line:

```
final Set<String> sessionsUsedByPrincipal = principals.get(principal);
```

The problem is that *sessionsUsedByPrincipal* gets a sessionId different from any sessionId stored on DB.
Any ideas why this is happening? I'll appreciate any comments or help.

**EDIT**

The answer worked great but it's logging twice. 
Here's the more important part of my *applicationContext-security*

```
<sec:http auto-config='false' use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">

    <sec:custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />
    <sec:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="preAuthFilter"/>
    <sec:custom-filter position="LOGOUT_FILTER" ref="logoutFilter"/>
    <sec:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"/>
</sec:http>

<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider" />
</sec:authentication-manager>

<bean id="preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" ref="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService"/>
</bean>
<bean id="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService"/>

<bean id="concurrencyFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
    <property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <property name="expiredUrl" value="/login.faces" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

<bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
    <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <property name="maximumSessions" value="-1" />
    <property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="simpleAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper" class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper">
    <property name="convertAttributeToUpperCase" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="webXmlMappableAttributesRetriever" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.j2ee.WebXmlMappableAttributesRetriever"/>

<bean id="j2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.j2ee.J2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource">
    <property name="mappableRolesRetriever" ref="webXmlMappableAttributesRetriever"/>
    <property name="userRoles2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper" ref="simpleAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper"/>
</bean>

<bean id="preAuthFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.j2ee.J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationDetailsSource" ref="j2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <constructor-arg value="/login.faces"/>
    <property name="forceHttps" value="false"/>     
</bean>

<bean id="logoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
    <constructor-arg value="/login.faces"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="cr.go.nov.proy.web.util.AccessLogHandler"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

I didn't write it and I don't fully understand it, I just added what I needed . Maybe you can take a look and see if something may be causing this behavior. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Spring Security is already clearing things for you also you shouldn't be extending `SecurityContextLogoutHandler` but implement your own `LogoutHandler` that will be added (as first!) to the chain. However I would suggest to implement an `ApplicationListener` that listens to `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` for succesful logins. The `WebAuthenticationDetails` also contains the session-id that is used or none if there isn't a session yet (your code forces session creation!). Also not sure why you want to expire the sessions (as spring will take care of that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters I suggest creating an `ApplicationListener` that listens to `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` and `InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent` events to start logging your access log.

To log the logout create a dedicated `LogoutHandler` instead of extending an existing one.

The session-id that will be used is part of the `WebAuthenticationDetails` so I would also suggest using that instead of working around it. Your code will force session creation if there isn't already a session.

```
public class AccessLogHandler implements ApplicationListener<AbstractAuthenticationEvent>, LogoutHandler {

    @Autowired
    private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

    @Autowired
    private AccessLogService accessLogService;

    public void onApplicationEvent(AbstractAuthenticationEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof AuthenticationSuccessEvent || event instanceof InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent) {
            Authentication authentication = event.getAuthentication();
            WebAuthenticationDetails details = (WebAuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails();
            accessLogService.addAccessLog("IP: "  + details.getRemoteAddress(), authentication.getName(), details.getSessionId());           
        }
    }

    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
            WebAuthenticationDetails details = (WebAuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails();
            accessLogService.closeAccessLog(Collections.singletonList(details.getSessionId());
            SessionInformation si = sessionRegistry.getSessionInformation(details.getSessionId());
            if (si != null) {
                si.expireNow();
            }
    }
}
```

Something like this should work and you can remove your extended classes, leaving you with a basic configuration. The `ApplicationListener` is registered automatically, the `LogoutHandler` you will need to add to the `LogoutFilter` which you need to explicitly configure I'm afraid. But judging by the fact that you already extended another `LogoutHandler` this is something you already do.

Your configuration is also quite verbose things like login, session control can be configured with the namespace. The following configuration should do the same as your own configuration (and probably a little more).

```
<sec:http auto-config='false' use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" >
    <sec:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="preAuthFilter"/>
    <sec:custom-filter position="LOGOUT_FILTER" ref="logoutFilter"/>
    <sec:login-form login-page="/login.faces" />
    <sec:session-management>
        <sec:concurrency-control max-sessions="-1" session-registry-alias="sessionRegistry" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" expired-url="/login.faces"/>
    </sec:session-management>
</sec:http>

<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider" />
</sec:authentication-manager>

<bean id="preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" ref="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService"/>

<bean id="j2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.j2ee.J2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource">
    <property name="mappableRolesRetriever">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.j2ee.WebXmlMappableAttributesRetriever"/>
    </property>
    <property name="userRoles2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper">
            <property name="convertAttributeToUpperCase" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="preAuthFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.j2ee.J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationDetailsSource" ref="j2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="logoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
    <constructor-arg value="/login.faces"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler"/>
            <bean class="cr.go.nov.proy.web.util.AccessLogHandler"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

In your configuration you don't register any `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` which also means no sessions are being registered with the `SessionRegistry`. As the `RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy` takes care of that. Note - This assumes that you are using Spring Security 3.2!

Comment: It worked perfectly thanks! But there's one detail... It's logging the session twice. I didn't do the **applicationContext-security** I just added the things I needed, would mind taking a look? maybe you can see if there's something causing this, I'll update my question with the file. Thanks again!

Comment: Did you, by accident, register the class twice? Or are you loading the xml file twice. If there are 2 instances of the bean it will be logged twice.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with register the class twice... and I found a problem, the session is not closing, I thought it was but it isn't. Apparently, when the new session is being registered is keeping a different sessionId, so my current sessiinId is never found to be closed. That's in **SessionRegistryImpl** the _registerNewSession_ function. I'm very confused...

Comment: The `SessionRegistry` isn't for closing session, the actual session is being closed by your container. The `SessionRegistry` only contains some metadata about the session not the actual `HttpSession` itself.

Comment: What I meant for registering twice make sure your security configuration is loaded only once (only by the `ContextLoaderListener` else beans will be duplicated and events will be processed twice. ).

Comment: In your configuration you should also really register a `SecurityContextLogoutHandler` which takes care of ending the http session and clearing the `SecurityContext`. In general you want to do this before your logging, which would also cleanup your sessions (as the session will be removed by the `SessionRegistry` itself, assuming that you have, as stated in the reference guide, configured the `HttpSessionEventPublisher`.

Comment: Yes, I know `SessionRegistry` doesn't close it, but it gets the session information...and there's the problem, it's not. `SessionInformation si = sessionRegistry.getSessionInformation(details.getSessionId())` returns null and that's why the container never expires the session. I do have the `HttpSessionEventPublisher` in my configuration, I'll check for the rest.

Comment: I can see at least 1 problem you both have a filter for session management and use the namespace. I suggest a cleanup of your security configuration as it is (too) verbose and can be reduced. You also seem to be missing registration of the `RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy` which registers new session in the `SessionRegistry`. I would suggest using the namespace as that would reduce your configuration you aren't doing anything, that, special that cannot be configured through the namespace. See my modified answer.

Comment: I'm using spring security 3.1... and as far as I can see `ContextLoaderListener` is the only one loading my security configuration